# jQuery appendTo all elements except last one

Tags: jquery, appendto

I am trying to append all elements of the same class "td.top" except last one to another place, but I can't figure out how is this possible.. Any ideas are welcomed, I am kind of stuck.. Thank you for any input. This is the code I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 960) {

$("td.top").appendTo("ul.sub");

} else {

//something else

}
});
```

Comment: Try `td.top:not(:last)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
$("td.top").not(":last").appendTo("ul.sub");
```

Comment: Or `$("td.top:not(:last)").appendTo("ul.sub");` (didnt wanted to make an answer for that).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon that works too, but the JQuery documentation suggests using the `not` method instead for readability purposes.

Comment: always fun to know all the options ;) and about readability, it is a personnal preference, even if i prefer `.not()` aswell.